# views slideshow: display multiple items but scroll only one item at the time

Tags: views

i'm using drupal 8 and slideshow module to create a block of slides (fields with images and descriptions to it) to put it on some pages.

I have managed to show slides horizontally and they scroll nicely but problem is how to show 4 slides and scroll only by one at the time.

In setting for slideshow there is an option "Items per slide" if i use it and put 4 - i will get 4 slides on an block but it will scroll 4 items at time.  If i put 1 - it will scroll one item at the time but will show only 1 slide and need 4.

plus to all that it should be responsive if only 3 slides can fit on the screen it should show 3 slides and scroll only one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using the [owl carousel](https://github.com/tabvn/owl) module from Git hub for responsive slide shows.  It has lots of options to define how many slides based on breakpoints, support for mobile touch events, number of slides per next, and more.

We've been using it since 8.0 without a problem.  Note that despite the Readme, the author has released it under GLPv2.  See issue #4.

There is a [cleaned up pull](https://github.com/anishsheela/owlcarousel) of this project as well.  I have not used this but it may be a slightly better alternative.

Just install the module as a manual module or you can add the git hub repo as a repository in your composer.json and install it via composer.  Once enabled, change your view format to Owl Carousel and then use the settings to define things.

Comment: owl carousel as far as i can tell is not stable for drupal8. and it is required Variable module which is not available for drupal8.

Comment: D'oh.. sorry, I thought this was the same as the module we've been using since 8.0... it's not.  Apparently this never made it off of Git hub.  Editing the answer with the Git Hub location.

Comment: CG Monroe,  I have tried it. it worked for me but one thing, there is no option to run carousel in circle (to loop the slideshow). there are new releases of owl carousel https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2 which in description says that there is loop option available... anyway now i have issues updating owl carousel, pls help.

Comment: Hmm, I am using v1.3 to do this.  There is an autoplay and rewind option in the view format settings that makes it run continuously.

Comment: I'm using jQuery OwlCarousel v1.3.3 but there is no option to run slides in loop. like in demo:  http://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/